# Using os.walk to find and print names of my files, but unable to open them? Path name issue?

Tags: python, python-2.7, path, ioerror

My relevant code block is as follows:

```
path = "\\Users\\Harmless\\Documents\\untitled"
cellorder = []
cellcont = []
for roots, dirs, files, in os.walk(path):
    for file in natural_sort(files):
        if "Row" in file:
            cellorder.append(file)
            with open(file,'r') as txt:
                print txt.readlines
            #print "file = %s" % file
```

This would successfully list all the files I want to open (as commented out), but when I try to pass in the filename the same way it was printed in order to read it:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Row0Col0Heat.txt'
```

How can I fix this? Do I need to reference the entire path name and string substitute in each filename? If so, why? Is there a better way to reference/utilize paths?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the absolute path of the file, you can get the absolute path by

```
abs_file_path = os.path.abspath(file)
```

since you already have the base path, you can also use:

```
abs_file_path = os.path.join(path, file)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: the path.join helped, but I now have a new problem: there is another layer of sub-directories between "untitled" and my txt files. I'd like to loop through and pull all txt files from each of these sub-directories, Any advice on how to handle this?

Comment: You should build your `abs_file_path` from `roots` not `path` as that holds the path to the current directory `os.walk` is currently in.

Comment: @TWReever Could you help me understand what that would look like?

Comment: Put a print statement inside the first for loop, that should clue you in. I think you'll find all you need to do is do an `os.path.join(roots, file)` and that will prepend the file name with it's path so the `open()` call will succeed.